# Must all codepaths return?

Tags: solidity

I'm currently reviewing the code of [RANDAO](https://github.com/randao/randao) and there is a function that does not return on all codepaths. Is this legal? Is the return value well defined in the case that the if statement does not hold?

```
  function returnRandom(Campaign storage c) bountyPhase(c.bnum) internal returns (uint256) {
      if (c.revealsNum == c.commitNum) {
          c.settled = true;
          return c.random;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a known bug/feature in Solidity: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/4751

There's plenty of discussions about it in the link and in its related issues but I fail to find a definitive consensus yet about what should be done about it.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, I did never try to write/saw something similar.

To verify if it could work, I wrote a minimal contract to verify whether it could work or not with the [REMIX IDE](http://remix.ethereum.org) (with Javascript VM).

```
  pragma ^0.4.24;
  contract A {
        function returnRandom(uint256 a) pure public returns (uint256) {
           if(a == 2) {
              return 5;
           }   
        }
  }
```

Surprisingly, this code does not produce warnings. When I run the code with an input different from 2, it returns 0.

I am sorry but I cannot explain the motivation for this design choice, which sounds odd ( I would expect at least a warning)

Comment: I also confirmed that it compiles - but what is really important is whether the return value is well-defined or undefined by the specification.